# class_name + object_name = new + class_name vs. Just typing "new + class_name": Whats the difference?

Tags: c#

So I already got used to using the "usual way of instantiating as a beginner" which is

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

And then I saw this:

```
new Employee {
//Some code here...
}
```

The employee class has this:

```
public class Employee{
    public string Name
    public Employee{ 
        Name = "Bob";
    }
}
```

So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Do you want a reference to the object or not?

Comment: Here is a good read for you that expains it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Comment: The posted `Employee` Class does not look like a valid class.

Comment: @Enigmativity Uhm, I dont really have any project going on with this question. I just saw this on a tutorial and I dunno about why did he put it in like that

Comment: @AaronAncheta - Try to verify the code and the issue you have with it before posting. Can you please do so now?